# How to check if Accessibility Shortcut (Volume key shortcut) is enabled?

Tags: android

[image]
[image]

How to programmatically check if Volume Key Shortcut is enabled? This shortcut enables accessibility services, which I don't need. I tried this:

```
AccessibilityManager am = (AccessibilityManager) getSystemService(ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE);
boolean isAccessibilityEnabled = am.isEnabled();
boolean isExploreByTouchEnabled = am.isTouchExplorationEnabled();
```

But this only returns true if any accessibility service (like TalkBack) is currently enabled, which is slightly different. What I need is to prevent enabling accessibility services when user press&hold volume up and volume down key buttons.

I could achieve this using:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell settings get secure accessibility_shortcut_enabled");
```

but this requires root

So If I know that it is enabled, I'll ask user to turn it off.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?